# Find an atlas for $H=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x_1+x_2^2=x_3^2+x_4=1\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Find an atlas for $H=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : x_1+x_2^2=x_3^2+x_4=1\}$

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto (x_1+x_2^2-1,x_3^2+x_4-1)$.

Then, $H=F^{-1}(0,0)$.

Since $DF_a:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto (x_1+2a_2x_2,2a_3x_3+x_4)$, is surjective, $H$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and its dimension is $4-2=2$.

Hence $H$ admits an atlas.

Is there any easy strategy to give an atlas of such varieties (ie, given by fibers)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest a careful reading of proof of the theorem you have cited, the one that proves $H$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^4$ of dimension~$2$. The way that proof works is to actually construct an atlas.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I found it a little confusing, and I'm beggining to study these things, maybe with an example I'd understand it better

Comment: Can you explain me in practise how to solve this? In theory things seem easy as we can say things like ''without loss of generality, we can suppose that the left $2 \times 2$ block of the jacobian matrix is invertible'', but in practise I don't see how to solve clearly this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\phi_1(u, v)=(u, \sqrt{1-u}, v, \sqrt{1-v})$$
$$\phi_2(u, v)=(u, \sqrt{1-u}, v, -\sqrt{1-v})$$
$$\phi_3(u, v)=(u, -\sqrt{1-u}, v, \sqrt{1-v})$$
$$\phi_4(u, v)=(u, -\sqrt{1-u}, v, -\sqrt{1-v})$$

Comment: I understand how you get those four charts, by parametrizing the surface $x_2=\pm \sqrt{1-x_1}$ and $x_3=\pm \sqrt{1-x_4}$. But parametrizing it $x_1=1-x_2^2$ and $x_4=1-x_3^2$, we get a global chart $\phi(u,v)=(1-u^2,u,v,1-v^2)$, isn't it?