# Find an atlas for $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1+z^2\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Find an atlas for $M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1+z^2\}$

It is easy for me to check that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $2$ using the following theorem:

> Let $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^\infty$ function on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and let $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
>
> Assume that for each $a \in F^{-1}(c)$, the derivative $DF_a:\mathbb{R}^{n+m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective.
>
> Then, $F^{-1}(c)$ has the structure of an $n$-dimensional manifold which is Hausdorff and has a countable basis of open sets.

I know also that the proof of this Theorem is to find an atlas, but in practise I have problems with construction that atlas.

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2-1$.

We have $DF_a=[2a_1 \quad 2a_2 \quad 2a_3]$, where $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Since $(0,0,0) \not \in M$, $DF_a$ has rank $1$, ie, $DF_a$ is surjective.

Then $M=F^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ os dimension $3-1=2$.

Now comes the part I don't understand.

We construct $G:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $G(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2-z^2-1,y,z)$.

Then, $$DG_a=\begin{bmatrix}
       2a_1 & 2a_2 & -2a_3 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}.$$

So the atlas is $\{(U_i,\varphi_i)\}_{1 \leq i \leq 3}$ where $U_i=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x_i \neq 0\}$.

But what is explicitly $\varphi_i:U_i \rightarrow \varphi(U_i)$?

Some help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one sheeted hyperboloid. You can find one parametrization rotating the hyperbola $(\cosh u, 0, \sinh u)$ to obtain: $${\bf x}(u,v) = (\cosh u \cos v, \cosh u \sin v, \sinh u), \quad u \in \Bbb R, \quad 0 < v < 2\pi.$$ This leaves out a meridian ($v = 0$). You can cover it taking any $\epsilon > 0$ and making $v \mapsto v+ \epsilon$ above. These two parametrizations will cover the surface.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do your answer follows the construction of the proof of the theorem given in the question?

Comment: No. The proof of the theorem, as far as I recall, uses the implicit/inverse function theorems to locally express the manifold as the graph of a differentiable function. I thought only of the revolution surface to come up with this.

Comment: Ok, but here the idea is to explain step by step how to obtain an atlas with this theorem, thing that I don't understand. Can you explain it?

Comment: Another option is to use two parametrizations $(u,v)\mapsto(u,v, \pm\sqrt{u^2+v^2-1})$. I like the revolution parametrization better for avoiding the square root, but that's me.

Comment: We commented at the same time. I think that my last suggestion does the job (graphs!)

Comment: Ok, I think that it's clear, but I'm afraid that this case is too simple. I posted another question of the same type (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318883/find-an-atlas-for-h-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-in-mathbbr4-x-1x-22-x-32x-4)

Comment: I have another problem, because I defined coordinate chart on a set $X$ to be a subset $U \subseteq X$ together with a bijection $\varphi:U \rightarrow \varphi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ onto an open set $\varphi(U)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Ie, we have $\varphi^{-1}$ instead of $\varphi$.

Comment: Then take $\varphi = {\bf x}^{-1}$. It will be easier to use the graph parametrizations instead of the revolution one..

Comment: I have edited the question with my attempts, ie, what I understand of the theorem